# converting delimeter of file to CSV fomat

Tags: linux, csv, ubuntu-12.04, delimiter

Well I am struck in a very basic problem

I have a file which has four attributes delimited by('::').

Following is what my attributes look like

```
a1::a2::a3::a4
```

Now I want the files to have the attributes like following(in Linux)

```
a1,a2,a3(without a4 and without '::')
```

what should I use?

Thanks

Comment: so u have 4 attribute in each line right ? you can go for small script if this is scenerio , i can make a small script for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the final attribute:

```
sed -e "s/::/,/g" -e "s/,[^,]*$//" <filename>
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas  ........but how was last attribute remove can you please tell me .........Sorry for asking but i  didn't get that

Comment: The first sed expression converts '::' to ','. The second expression matches a semicolon and all characters that are not a semicolon until the end of the line - that's the last attribute.